# Fail to use Provider and Get Data: Tried to call Provider.of<dynamic>

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, provider

I am failing to retrieving boolean value from firestore/firebase via Provider.

The error message in image:
[image]

The getter is below where the issue seems to come from:

```
    _getProfileData(AuthNotifier authNotifier) async {
      final uid = await Provider.of<AuthNotifier>(context, listen: false).getCurrentUID();
    await Provider.of(context, listen: false)
        .collection('Users')
        .document(uid)
        .get().then((result) {
          user.isAdmin = result.data['isAdmin'];
    });
  }]
```

Below Future builder using the data from Provider.

```
future: _getProfileData(authNotifier),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              _isAdmin = snapshot.data['isAdmin'] ?? false;
            }
            return Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  adminFeature(),
                  ]
```

Below, I have auth notifier to retrieve data from firebase.

```
  Future<String> getCurrentUID() async {
    return (await _firebaseAuth.currentUser()).uid;
  }

  // GET CURRENT USER
  Future getCurrentUser() async {
    return await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
  }
```

```
class User {
  List favorites = [];  
  String documentID;
  String displayName;
  String email;
  String password;
  bool isAdmin;

  User({
    this.favorites,
    this.documentID,
    this.displayName, 
    this.email,
    this.password,
    this.isAdmin,

    });

  factory User.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot document) {
    Map data = document.data;

    return User(
      favorites: data['favorite'] ?? [],
      documentID: document.documentID,
      displayName: data['displayName'] ?? '',
      email: data['email'] ?? '',
      isAdmin: data['isAdmin'] ?? false,
    );
  }

  // get admin => null;
    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'displayName': displayName,
      'email': email,
      'isAdmin': isAdmin,
    };
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: It will be helpful to see your data structure as you might not be retrieving the required boolean.

Comment: Hi  Andrew, i added the structure for Users.

Answer (score 0):

```
await Provider.of(context, listen: false) //<--- here is your problem, you don't define the type of Provider
   .collection('Users')
   .document(uid)
   .get().then((result) {
     user.isAdmin = result.data['isAdmin'];
});
```

change it to something like this

```
await Provider.of<FirebaseFirestore>(context, listen: false)...the rest of your code...
```

Comment: thanks, I tried before this, however, The method 'collection' isn't defined for the type 'User'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'collection'

Comment: Type user? The method collection is of FirebaseFirestore, where are you using or declaring the providers?

Comment: Also your future builder expected some data of type map (snapshot.data['isAdmin]) but your method never returns anything, instead of await the provider you should return the provider value or something

Comment: hi, EdwynZN, it should be done in authNotifier.

Comment: That error is unrelated to the one posted, update where does the error occurs and what did you change to have this new error

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use User of T, instead of only User:

```
return User<T>( // <--- Here
      favorites: data['favorite'] ?? [],
      documentID: document.documentID,
      displayName: data['displayName'] ?? '',
      email: data['email'] ?? '',
      isAdmin: data['isAdmin'] ?? false,
);
```